# How to add font awesome in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a an icon from font awesome but for some reason it does not appear when I load the page.
Below is my html code in which I attempted to add the font awesome in different ways.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Media Queries</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial=scale1.0">  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">      
    </head>
    <body> 
        <i class="fa fa-car" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <h1>
            <i class="fa fa-car" aria-hidden="true"></i>Dummy Text
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there anything that am missing in the code?

Comment: Check console for any error.

Comment: Try loading the font-awesome from `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css` instead of your local files

Comment: It worked perfectly.
Still wondering the possible reason for the other way not working but will use that way so long.

Comment: Have you cheked it. @import url('/font-awesome-4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you put in your link is the name of your folder.You should put the name of the file instead(font-awesome)

On the font-awesome folder look for the file called font-awesome,copy and paste on your browser text field so that you can see the correct path.
Copy that path and paste in your link like this:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
```

Just check the path correctly cause I see no other mistake.
let me know if it does not work.

Answer (score 11):

You can add font-awesome css file in your "**main.css**" file

```
@import url('/font-awesome-4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css');
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are planning to use CDN just add one line it to your css file (i.e. main.css) indicating from where the font style should be imported

```
@import url('https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
```

source of the link used in the example above: https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/

Answer (score 2):

Try to call form font-awesome like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Or if you try from your site folder then download font-awesome and add fonts into your fonts folder and add font-awesome css into css folder
then call it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
```